# No entiendo lo que se dice de las medallas curioso, inquisidor y socrático

Tags: discusión, preguntas, medallas

No entiendo absolutamente nada de lo que se afirma sobre las medallas:

- *Curioso:* Formula una pregunta que sea bien recibida en 5 días diferentes y mantén un registro de preguntas positivas
- *Inquisidor:* Formula una pregunta que sea bien recibida en 30 días diferentes y mantén un registro de preguntas positivas
- *Socrático:* Formula una pregunta que sea bien recibida en 100 días diferentes y mantén un registro de preguntas positivas

Ni sé lo que significa: ***una pregunta que sea bien recibida en X días consecutivos***, ni tampoco ***mantén un registro de preguntas positivas***.

¿Alguien podría explicarlo?

¿Creen que expuesto así queda claro cuando uno lo lee? Yo al menos no entiendo nada de nada.

Comment: Creo, de acuerdo a lo que he visto, en que formules al menos una pregunta por dia cuya calificacion sea >= 1, por lo lo cual si durante 5 dias formulas 5 preguntas, obtienes la primera medalla de bronze, creo que es asi

Comment: @IvanBotero además, ninguna de ellas debe estar cerrada ni eliminada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se trata de contar cuántos días has formulado alguna *buena* pregunta y ninguna *mala*, así como tu consistencia haciéndolo. Si lo haces *bien* en 5 días, consigues la medalla Curioso. Si perseveras y lo consigues en 30 días diferentes, tienes Inquisidor. Si sobresales y lo haces 100 días, te dan la de Socrático.

De una forma más objetiva:

> Formula una pregunta que sea bien recibida en X días diferentes

Que al menos una de tus preguntas en ese día concreto tenga una puntuación >= 1, no esté eliminada y esté abierta. Además, que ninguna otra pregunta formulada ese día esté cerrada, ni tenga puntuación negativa ni esté borrada.

> mantén un registro de preguntas positivas

`(total preguntas - preguntas con puntaje negativo - cerradas - borradas)/total preguntas ≥ 0.5`

Más info en [Badges for habitually asking well-received questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262301/1983854)

---

Ejemplos de días en los que el contador **sí** sumaría uno:

```
         puntuación     cerrada      eliminada
día 1       0             no             no
día 1       0             no             no
día 1       1             no             no

día 2       1             no             no

día 3       5             no             no
día 3       5             no             no
día 3       5             no             no
```

Ejemplos de días en los que el contador **no** sumaría:

```
         puntuación     cerrada      eliminada
día 1       5             no             no
día 1       5             no             no
día 1       5             no             sí
# una de ellas está eliminada

día 2       5             no             no
día 2       5             no             no
día 2       5             sí             no
# una de ellas está cerrada

día 3       0             no             no
día 3       0             no             no
día 3       0             no             no
# ninguna tiene puntuación positiva
```

Comment: Y sí, la descripción es rara.

Comment: Una sola pregunta al día. Si hago dos preguntas en el mismo día y ambas tiene votos positivos, el contador solo sube un punto. #verificado

Comment: Gracias, pero sigo sin entenderlo del todo. ¿Se refiere a _una pregunta_  o es un registro que se calcula a nivel de todas las preguntas?

Comment: @A.Cedano es un registro. Añadí ejemplos para intentar hacerlo más entendible. Resumiendo, en un día dado solamente puedes sumar 1 en esta cuenta.